# How many paraphyletic groups can be formed from a phylogeny?

Tags: bioinformatics, homework

How many paraphyletic groups can theoretically be created from this phylogeny?

[image]

I found (2<sup>n</sup>)-2. Is this correct?
This is not homework nor exam, just a question about paraphyletic groups.

Answer (score 1):

If we define a paraphyletic group as any group on a phylogeny that is not monophyletic, I count there to be 2^n - 2*n paraphyletic groups for a fully ladderized tree with n tips.

There are 2^n possible groups of n species. Of these groups, 2*n of them are monophyletic: n groups containing a single species, and n groups containing multiple species.

Comment: I cant find a good explanation for paraphyletic group, what are all possible para. Groups if n=3?

Comment: @Nemexia The term "paraphyletic" doesn't really have a hard definition, but the way I defined it, a tree with 3 tips will have 2^3 - 2*3 = 2 paraphyletic groups: {1,3} and {2,3}.

Comment: Why arent these paraphyltic? {1,2} with common ancestor( first and secound node)?

Comment: {1,2} is a monophyletic group because it contains all descendants of the MRCA of {1,2} (the ancestor of {1,2} only has 1 and 2 as descendants, so the {1,2} group is monophyletic.